# How to access a list of lists elements

Tags: r

I want to access the different attributes of the list-type variable 'o', through a variable 'i' inside a loop. For example, second element of the list would be the list:

```
o$'2'
## [1] "11938" "11939" "11940" "11941" "11942" "11943" "11944" "11945" "11946"
```

and the first element of the second element of the list:

```
o$'2'[1]
## [1] "11938"
```

I have tried the following for the first case with no success:

```
i=2;
o$paste("\"",i,"\"",sep="")
```

Comment: If you only want to *print* the quotes just do  `paste(o$"2")`. If you want to convert it to a character class, do `o$"2" <- as.character(o$"2")`

Comment: Thanks David, just reedited to be clearer.

Comment: How about accessing the list elements by `o[[i]]` and `o[[i]][1]`?

Comment: You need to use the `[[` operator instead of the `$` and notice that you have the `'` quote and not `"`. Try `o[[paste("'",i,"'",sep="")]]`

Comment: Thanks Marat, missing the double bracket. Nicola, you can access the element either with single or doublet quote, many thanks.